# kafkajs "The coordinator is not aware of this member" error

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to add consumers for a topic using kafkajs (v2.0.0) on my node project.
i am trying to add a consumer, using example [provided in the docs](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consumer-example)

creating the client:

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
    logLevel: logLevel.DEBUG,
    brokers: brokers
})
```

creating the group

```
const consumer = kafka.consumer({groupId:'some unique group id'})
```

followed by async run call to .connect, .subscribe .run

However, i am getting the follwing error when calling .consumer()

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response JoinGroup(key: 11, version: 5)","broker":"","clientId":"","error":"The coordinator is not aware of this member","correlationId":,"size":}
```

in DEBUG:

```
The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
```

```
the error is thrown after 
[Cluster] Found group coordinator
[Connection] Request JoinGroup
[Connection] Response JoinGroup <----- error
```

**Attempt 1**
using default values, passing in a unique groupId, like:

```
const consumer = kafka.consumer({groupId:'someGroup'})
```

Actual result:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response JoinGroup(key: 11, version: 5)","broker":"","clientId":"","error":"The coordinator is not aware of this member","correlationId":,"size":}
```

**Attempt 2**
Increased session timeout value
Decreased heartbeat interval value
*kept the heartbeat 1/3 of the session timeout as suggested in the docs

Actual result:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response JoinGroup(key: 11, version: 5)","broker":"","clientId":"","error":"The coordinator is not aware of this member","correlationId":,"size":}
```

**Attempt 3**
When i run the consumer via CLI directly on the broker while explicitly setting --group with the group id
only then i am able to proggermaticaly call .consumer using the example script w/o seeing this error

Actual result:
consumer is added to the previously create group

**Attempt 4**
i tried the same example using a different library ([kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node))

Actual result: Consumer group created with no issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! Do you have some tips about this? Im having exactly the same issue and don't know what to to.